# Blazor server in production on azure: Works for a while then suddenly 404 on all css/script files?

Tags: azure, blazor-server-side, static-files, .net-5

I hope its okay to ask here, I could not find a specific existing thread for this.

I have developed a Blazor server application in .NET 5 for a client, and it has been hosted on azure app service (on Linux plan). We have several environments (Dev, test,prod), and the deployed app works as intended in all environments, except when deployed to the production app. It works fine for a while, but at a point something happens and the browser dev tools console says 404 not found for all the css and script files. Because it is .NET 5, application insights are not supported in Azure.

In the Program.cs's CreateHostBuilder I have added the UseStaticWebAssets, and in Configuration in Startup.cs app.UseStaticFiles.

And as mentioned, it works perfect in all other environments, and for a while it works good in production after restarting the App Service.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks!
Morten

Comment: `Because it is .NET 5, application insights are not supported in Azure.` I seriously doubt that. .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5 and [the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore) targets .NET Standard 2.0, so it *does* work on .NET Core.

Comment: As for a 404 after a while -  did the service shut down due to inactivity perhaps? Or did the application crash due to some error? Both of these things should be logged by Azure

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It actually isnt, if you have an app service configured for .NET 5, application insights is greyed out with a text "application insights not supported for .NET 5".

Comment: You mean *Visual Studio* doesn't add it automatically. The package is there though. Again, .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. If you configure the service and add the package, it will work. That's explained in the relevant [Github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2119) and [Microsoft Answers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/200011/when-azure-app-service-for-net-5-support-applicati.html). Check the Azure logs first though. A service going down should be logged. If you enable StdOut logging, it will also be available somewhere